# Jquery select2- how to select all search results

Tags: jquery-select2

Currently select2 allows me to select only one option at a time after the list is filtered with search term.

Ex: Lets say the list contains all US states and my search term is "New"
    what I want is to be able to select all search results based on the search term, in this case New York, New Mexico, New Hampshire, New Jersey, I need to select all at once.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

did a work around, now its working

had to set placeholder with the search term value and then did another search on all the elements with javascript string includes function to get those elements.

```
function onSelectAll(clicked_id) {  
var parentid = $('#'+clicked_id).parent().attr("id");
var search = $('#'+parentid+' .select2-search__field').attr("placeholder"); 
var elements = document.getElementById(clicked_id).options;

if(search){
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if(elements[i].value.includes(search)) {
            elements[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
else {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){       
          elements[i].selected = true;
    }
}
  var vv = $('#'+clicked_id).val();
    $('#'+clicked_id).val(vv).trigger('change');
```

}